# 実行ファイルのあるディレクトリの兄弟ディレクトリの絶対パスを得たい

Tags: python

今、aというフォルダにあるスクリプトを実行しているとして、そのスクリプトでaと同じ階層のbというフォルダ内のc.pyの絶対pathを取得したいです。

aとbは例えばdという名前の同じフォルダー内にあるということです。

Comment: 説明が至らなくて申し訳ありません。
aの中にbというフォルダがあるという訳ではありません。
aとbは例えばdという名前の同じフォルダー内にあると仮定しています。
os.path.~を利用して絶対pathを取得したいです。

Comment: `print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../b/c.py"))` という事でしょうか？

Comment: argusさんのコメントで解決しましたか？ それともimportなどがやりたいのですか？

Comment: 解決しました。実際にはもうひとつos.path.dirnameを用いて上の階層を指定しました。

Comment: @tぐち 自己解決した場合はご自身で回答を書いてからそれを承認してみてください。そうするとこの質問は解決済みとしてマークされるので SOでは推奨されてます。

Answer (score 1):

コメントより

> 解決しました。実際にはもうひとつos.path.dirnameを用いて上の階層を指定しました。

Answer (score 0):

bフォルダ以下にあるものを`import`するためには`__init__.py`を置く必要があります。
`__init__.py`の中身は空で良いです。
このファイルが置かれている場所は`import`で指定できるようになります。

**フォルダ構成**

```
a/
├ hoge.py
└ b/
  ├ __init__.py
  └ c.py
```

**hoge.py**

```
from b.c import something

something()
```

**c.py**

```
def something():
    print('test')
```

ちなみに`import`の仕方は`import b.c`としても良いです。
ただ、そうインポートした場合は、メソッドを呼ぶ際に`b.c.something()`とする必要があります。

クラス定義も同様に呼び出すことができます。

**hoge.py**

```
from b.c import something, TestClass

something()

test_class = TestClass()
test_class.something()
```

**c.py**

```
def something():
    print('test')


class TestClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def something(self):
        print('class test')
```

詳細はドキュメントを確認してください。
http://docs.python.jp/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages